# DateTime deserialization

Tags: .net, json, couchbase-lite

I am having some troubles deserialzing a json string. I am getting following string from my db

{"myobject":{"Make":null,"Model":null,"StartVin":null,"KerbWeight":null,"Engine":null,"TrimLevel":null,"SafetyPack":null,"BodyType":null,"FullDescription":null,"ReleaseDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","HandOfDrive":null,"VehicleClass":null,"RawImage":null,"Dimension":{"Width":0,"Height":0,"Length":0},"FrontProfile":[{"Index":1,"Offset":0},{"Index":2,"Offset":0},{"Index":3,"Offset":0},{"Index":4,"Offset":0},{"Index":5,"Offset":0},{"Index":6,"Offset":0},{"Index":7,"Offset":0}],"RearSeats":{"Height":0,"Angle":0,"Fore":0,"ArmRests":0,"SeatBaseTilt":0,"BeltAnchorage":0,"LumbarSupport":0,"HeadRestraingHeight":0,"HeadRestraintTilt":0},"Id":null,"Type":"adas-test.vehicle","Name":""**,"User":"XX\myname","Owner":"xx\myname","Tag":null,"CreateDate":"2018-07-22T20:59:21.1403323+00:00","ModifyDate":"2018-07-22T20:59:21.1403323+00:00"**,"FrontSeats50Percentile":{"Height":0,"Angle":0,"Fore":0,"ArmRests":0,"SeatBaseTilt":0,"BeltAnchorage":0,"LumbarSupport":0,"HeadRestraingHeight":0,"HeadRestraintTilt":0},"FrontSeats5Percentile":{"Height":0,"Angle":0,"Fore":0,"ArmRests":0,"SeatBaseTilt":0,"BeltAnchorage":0,"LumbarSupport":0,"HeadRestraingHeight":0,"HeadRestraintTilt":0},"FrontSeats95Percentile":{"Height":0,"Angle":0,"Fore":0,"ArmRests":0,"SeatBaseTilt":0,"BeltAnchorage":0,"LumbarSupport":0,"HeadRestraingHeight":0,"HeadRestraintTilt":0},"SeatArrangementFrontRow":null,"SeatArrangementSecondRow":null,"SeatArrangementThirdRow":null,"SteeringWheelSetting":{"Horizontal5P":0,"Vertical5P":0,"Horizontal50P":0,"Vertical50P":0},"VehiclePreparation":{"FuelTankCapacity":0,"WheelArchHeight":0,"TyrePressure":0}}}

then i am simply doing

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)

i get my object but things highlighted are not serialized... all other things are. What could be the problem with the datetimehandling? and why is owner not deserialized?

for serialization i have used

DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset

because couchdb only allows timeoffset

TY